# C++ UDP Socket not working to send back from server to client after receiving first packets from client

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, hole-punching

Writing a UDP client-server app in C++ (done that lots of times before in many languages in the past 15 years), but somehow this one is not working correctly.

I cannot post actual code nor minimal reproducible app at the moment but I am willing to pay for live help if anyone is available to help solve this quickly with screensharing.

I think this is a particularity with C++ sockets and the way I am using them in this specific app which is quite complex.

Basically the issue is that the packets sent from the server to the client are not received by the client, only when said client is on a separate nat. 
When both in same local networking and using their local IP, everything works as expected.

Here is what I am doing :

1. Client `sendto(...)` packets through UDP to the server using a specific server host and port 12345 (and keeps sending these non-stop)
2. On another thread, client `bind(...)` on port 12345 and "0.0.0.0" and tries to `poll()` and `recvfrom()` in a loop (poll always returns 0 here when client is on a separate nat)
3. Server `bind()` on port 12345 and "0.0.0.0" then `poll()` and `recvfrom()` in a loop
4. Upon receiving the first UDP message from a client, it starts a thread for sending
   UDP messages back to the client **on a new socket**, using the
   sockaddr_in that it got from the `recvfrom()` to pass in the `sendto()` commands.

Result : Server perfectly receives ALL messages from all clients, and sends all messages back to all clients, but any client that is not on the same NAT will never receive any messages (`poll()` always returns 0).

As far as I understand it, when the client sends a UDP message to the server on a specific remote port (12345 in this case), it will punch a hole in its NAT so that it can receive messages back from the remote server on that port...

I tested five different client network configurations :

1. Local network with the server, using local IP addresses (WORKS)
2. Local network with the server while client is using a VPN thus going through a remote NAT (DOES NOT WORK)
3. Local network with the server but client is using the WAN ip address to connect to the server (DOES NOT WORK)
4. Client at an actual remote network from a friend's connection, behind a router (DOES NOT WORK)
5. Client going through a wifi hotspot created using my phone (DOES NOT WORK)

For all tests above, the server was correctly receiving all communications from clients.

I also tried forcing the port to 12345 for the `sendto()` instead of using the sockaddr_in as set from `recvfrom()`, same issue.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

If you want to help but need to see actual code, I can do that live with screen sharing and I will pay for the help.

Thanks.

Also, if anyone can point me to a great site where I can pay for VERY QUICK help, please let me know, I don't even bother searching google because I really want actual advice from people who tried these services, not ads trying to rip me off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the original receiver socket is allowed to reply to the client, because it's the client request that opens the port in the NAT. So either use the same socket in the server to receive and reply, or get the port that the second server socket was bound to and transfer it with an initial message through the original server port, so that A can send to it and punch the hole.

It looks so strange to create two half duplex sockets when a socket is a full duplex communication object that I'd go with the first option.

Comment: Okay that seems like great information and very helpful if that's true ! 
However I would have to completely rewrite my networking system if using the option 1... And I am unsure I understand the option 2 (isn't it what I am already doing ?) 
The reason I use multiple half duplex sockets is that I really need each client to be on their own individual threads on the server CPU so that it's as fast as possible, and my implementation does not require "Answers" between client and server, but rather they are both ways just doing data streaming that require very low latency and not reliability.

Comment: No, after you bind the second server socket there will be a new server port number (say, 54321) that you need to send back to the client. Either you chose that port, so you already know it, or you let the system to automatically bind it (for example, by calling sendto without binding). In this case, you'll need getsockname() to get the newly allocated port number. Either call bind by hand with a known port, or for a dynamic way would separate control and data sockets, so that you have one control socket that distributes newly allocated port numbers. As long as the client sends to the port, it

Comment: Okay, it works now, I simply passed the same file descriptor to my new socket abstraction so that it uses the same raw socket to send messages... Thanks a lot !! 
It seems I can't "Accept" your answer for some reason...